# Why isn't this simple jQuery block not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The jQuery:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#links .button").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr("id") + "-fade";
        $("#sliding-blocks").fadeOut(100);
        $("#" + id).fadeIn(300);
    });
});
```

And the simplified HTML:

```
<table id="links">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="projects" class="button">
                Projects
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table id="sliding-blocks">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span id="projects-fade" class="block">
                <img class="icon" src="github.png" height="20" width="20" />
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The non-simplified HTML contains more entries in `#links` and `#sliding-blocks`, but all following the same "fade" naming convention.

For some reason, I can't get anything to work (not even something I can work from). And yes, I've loaded jQuery.

Solution:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    var blocks = ["projects-fade", "blog-fade", "online-fade", "resume-fade"];
    $("#links .button").click(function() {
        var id = this.id + "-fade";
        $("#sliding-blocks").fadeOut(100,function() {
            $.each(blocks, function() {
                $("#" + this).hide();
            });
            $("#" + id).show();
            $(this).fadeIn(300);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: you are fading out the table which contains the element that you want to display

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you've faded out an ancestor of the element you're trying to fade in.

When the ancestor is faded out, none of its descendants will be visible.

I assume you're looking for something like this...

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#links .button").click(function() {
        var id = this.id + "-fade";
        $("#sliding-blocks").fadeOut(100,function() {
            $("#" + id).show();
            $(this).fadeIn(300);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I added a small function to your implementation (see my question if you're interested).

Comment: @MaxMackie: That looks good, although if you want to hide the others, you could also select them by class `$(".block").hide()`, eliminating the need for the Array and the `$.each`.

Comment: Right! I forgot about that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Your fade out the `#sliding-blocks` table, and fade in one element of it, but the table itself is still faded out. You should instead fade out all `.block` elements, then fade in the one you want, leaving the table visible all the time.

Comment: I'd assume the .block elements have display:block, otherwise they wont fade.

Answer (score 2):

you're hiding sliding-blocks and then your're trying to fade a child element of it in. that won't work as the parent container sliding-blocks is invisible